# Remember Appointment - without mobile phone

Tags: organization, office, work

I have the tunnel vision. I know that I have an telco at 14:00 this day. But if a team mate asks me for help at 13:45, then I walk to his desk and then it is likely that I forget the telco.

An alarm app on my mobile phone does not help, since I usually don't carry my mobile phone with me if I go to the room of a team mate.

I don't want to wear these huge "smart" watches which need to be charged (battery) often.

A small watch or other device would be ok. But I want to charge the device only once a week.

Or is there an other live hack which could help me having the tunnel vision?

Comment: I was not aware of "Personal Productivity site" What should I do now? Create the same question there and close this here?

Comment: I got no guide what to do after this question was put on hold ...ok... I created a new question here: https://productivity.stackexchange.com/questions/18128/remember-appointment-without-mobile-phone I hope this was the right thing.

Answer (score 3):

In the olden days, the state-of-the-art reminder hack was a short piece of solid-state string.

Tie the string around your finger to remind you that something must be done and you'll remember to fill-in the details. It's hard to ignore, has no battery issues, it's re-useable, re-cycleable, can't be left behind, and it's as close to you as …

Well, 'nuf said. Here's the hack, illustrated.

[image: string on finger]

Comment: Yes, this works very well if the topic is "I need to foo today. It does not matter if I do it at 10:00 or 12:00". Yes, this works. If I talk about interesting topics of if I do software development, then time flies. If I need to do something at an exact date and time, then this method won't be as reliable as I want it to be. I love solving real world brain teasers (head nuts, couts), but if I do appointments are not on my mind.

Comment: @guettli My bet is that the combination of visual and sensual distraction will be just sufficient to derail your train of thought enough to remind you to check the time. Try it. Surprise yourself.

Answer (score 1):

The simplest way to fix this is improve your memory - it is very easy to do, and it responds well to practice.

If you honestly can't remember these sorts of things, why not go old school:

Have a small notepad. Whenever you need to context switch or add a new task, look at your notepad. You'll see you have a call at 14:00 - and tell your colleague you can help him but **you need to be back at your desk for 14:00**

Now you both know, which makes it much easier to remember.

Comment: I want to focus on one thing. If I talk to team mates, I don't want a small part of my brain to think at appointments. I want a tool, that is more reliable than my brain. My brain is not well suited to do multitasking.

Comment: I think you are making this more difficult than it needs to be. You don't need to **use** brain power for this. It's not multi tasking. A watch, timer, phone, anything will work.